# Field Label Extraction in pdfBox Java

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdf-form

*Is it possible to retrieve the label of the form field in pdfBox Java?*
I am only able to get the fully or partial names, unable to gets labels of the fields.

Comment: AcroForm fields do not have labels.

Comment: Is there any way to get the name near the AcroForm fields

Comment: You can do text extraction in the vicinity of the field. But you should have an idea where label texts for your form usually are located, e.g. are they usually in front of the matching field?

Comment: How to get the vicinity of the field.

Comment: The Region Extracted by Widget getRectangle() method of field element doesn't match with the Rectangle2D region that has to be specified to extract the text using PDFTextStripperByArea.

Comment: Yes, that is a PDFBox quirk. Text extraction uses somewhat normalized coordinates.

Comment: Any other solutions to retrieve the field label? Does any other Java API provide a solution for this?

Comment: As there is no explicit recognizable label in AcroForms, APIs usually don't expose one. Text extraction, on the other hand, is a feature most PDF libraries offer. Switching to a different PDF library, therefore, will make the code look a bit different but your task itself won't become easier.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve the boxes like rectangle, circle from the pdf file? Will there be any link between the box and the form field that is present within the box?

Comment: *Will there be any link between the box and the form field that is present within the box* - it depends... If the f box is part of the form field appearance, it is strongly linked. If it is merely part of the page content, there is no immediate link.

Comment: If you hope for more detailed answers or hints here, you had better edit your question to provide a representative PDF form and probably also show the pivotal code you have yet.